# Odrive Unofficial - This snap has been emptied due to security concerns

Tags: snap, drive

Using Ubuntu 20.04

I have installed the newest version of odrive-unofficial.
i also reinstalled snapd by
`sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine && sudo apt install -y snapd`

However, every time i try to run the drive i only get
`sudo odrive-unofficial`

> ```
> This snap has been emptied due to security concerns.
> Press any key to exit.
> ```

What is wrong?

Comment: why do you run `odrive-unofficial` with `sudo` ?

Comment: to work around eventual permission complications. It also does not work without sudo.

Comment: Then try deb-package https://github.com/liberodark/ODrive/releases .

Comment: Someone else [has the same issue](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/opendrive/26117). And this is also the only result when doing a google search for the error ...